# Sql Server 2005 Fulltext case sensitivity problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, full-text-search, freetext

I seem to have a weird bug in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 where `FREETEXT()` searches are somewhat case-sensitive despite the collation being case-insensitive (`Latin1_General_CI_AS`).

First of, `LIKE` queries are perfectly case-insensitive, so

```
WHERE column LIKE '%word%'
```

and

```
WHERE column LIKE '%Word%'
```

return the same results.

Also, `FREETEXT` are infact case-insensitive to some extent, for instance

```
WHERE FREETEXT(column, 'Word')
```

will return results with different cases.

BUT

```
WHERE FREETEXT(column, 'word')
```

while still returning case-insensitive matches for `word`, gives a different resultset.
Or, as I found out after some investigation, searching for `word` gives all matches for different cases of `word` but searching for `Word` gives the same PLUS inflectional results.

Or to use one of the actual cases I found, searching for `marketingleader` returns all results containing that word, independent of the case, whereas searching for `Marketingleader` would return those, but also results that just contain `leader` that don't show up when searching for the lower case.

has anyone got any Idea as to what is causing this and how I could turn on inflectional/fuzzy searching for lower-case words as well?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the alternative to `freetext` which is `contains` and the inflectional results are optional ..

[CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

.. oups just saw that you mention contains in your question, but does it behave the same way as the freetext in the provided examples ?

Comment: oh, I just realized I forgot to reset the database model cache on the website, so when I tested it with `Contains`, it was actually still using `freetext`, so you are indeed correct.

Only problem now is that `contains` only does inflectional searches when using `FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, 'term')` whereas `FREETEXT` does it per default (well, except for the weird case I'm experiencing, of course).
There seems to be no easy way to get inflectional & thesaurus searching working by default?

Comment: when you use the FORMSOF for inflectional and thesaurus does it return different results than the freetext ?

Comment: `FORMSOF`, be it inflectional or with thesaurus, doesn't return any results other than literal matches for some terms where `FREETEXT` does... 

On second thoughts, it might not be `FORMSOF` /inflectional related at all, but rather has to do with word breaking being somewhat casesensitive i.e. only performed when the first letter is uppercase. Could this be language related? The database language is german.

Well, I could just uppercase the first letters of all search terms programatically, I guess

Comment: I have had issues myself (it might have been my mistake though.. never resolved it) with word rules for greek language ..

Are the search terms always going to be full words ? (i do not know the content of the application, so it could be that someone would search for an ending to a word)

..just saying ..

Comment: it's a job search engine, so people mostly search for jobtitles.
Full phrases seem unlikely (at least given the search history/popularity of search terms, most searches are for compound words)